# Internet VPN Tunnel with a server behind NAT

Tags: windows-7, vpn, nat

Let's say someone would like to route all their traffic traffic though some PC in another country (to unblock some sites). However, this PC is a usual Windows 7 PC behind a router with NAT, which somewhat complicates the configuration. To gain access to it via a stable host name, DDNS and DMZ are enabled on the router and an incoming connection was created to allow VPN clients connect.

Now a VPN connection can be established, but it only gives access to this particular PC. To get access back to the Internet one would need to route all the packets from VPN to the LAN interface. In Windows XP, I managed to do so by configuring NAT with `netsh routing ip nat`, which worked well. But in Windows 7 they have removed this feature. Is there some way I can enable it or some alternative solution? Can perhaps `route` command be of help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution: [NAT32](http://www.nat32.com). Excellent free program, which can be configured to route the packets between the interfaces. Works in Windows XP, 7, 8.

Answer (score 0):

- Open Network Connections
- Get Properties on the VPN connection
- On the Networking tab, get Properties on IPv4
- Advanced...
- "Use default gateway on remote network"

That should make all traffic sent over the VPN.

Comment: This option is only available on the client computer and makes no difference for the server.